# PowerPoint VBA - Theme Color Formula

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I want to mimic how PowerPoint automatically chooses a color after the 6 accent colors are used.

In vba you can set the 6 theme colors like this:

```
.ThemeColorScheme(msoThemeAccent1) = RGB(255, 0, 0)
.ThemeColorScheme(msoThemeAccent2) = RGB(0, 255, 0)
.ThemeColorScheme(msoThemeAccent3) = RGB(0, 255, 255)
.ThemeColorScheme(msoThemeAccent4) = RGB(255, 255, 0)
.ThemeColorScheme(msoThemeAccent5) = RGB(23, 255, 10)
.ThemeColorScheme(msoThemeAccent6) = RGB(23, 255, 100)
```

The theme colors are manually set here:

[image]

Lets say I have a chat with 15 series, powerpoint will use the first 6 account colors but then it automatically picks rgbs which are slightly lighter or darker based on the first 6 accent colors. I want this formula so I can tweak it to my liking. Is this forumla available anywhere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The color transformation algorithms have never been published, but they're easy enough to deduce:

1. Create a sample chart with as many data series as you need.
2. Save the file, change the ending to .zip and unzip.
3. Look at ppt/charts/chart1.xml

Office programs don't directly transform RGB values. Instead, they apply filters. Here is a color fill typical of the first 6 series':

```
<a:solidFill>
    <a:schemeClr val="accent1"/>
</a:solidFill>
```

Second group of 6:

```
<a:solidFill>
    <a:schemeClr val="accent1">
        <a:lumMod val="60000"/>
    </a:schemeClr>
</a:solidFill>
```

Third group:

```
<a:solidFill>
    <a:schemeClr val="accent1">
        <a:lumMod val="80000"/>
        <a:lumOff val="20000"/>
    </a:schemeClr>
</a:solidFill>
```

Fourth group:

```
    <a:schemeClr val="accent1">
        <a:lumMod val="80000"/>
    </a:schemeClr>
</a:solidFill>
```

Fifth group:

```
<a:solidFill>
    <a:schemeClr val="accent1">
        <a:lumMod val="60000"/>
        <a:lumOff val="40000"/>
    </a:schemeClr>
</a:solidFill>
```

Sixth group:

```
<a:solidFill>
    <a:schemeClr val="accent1">
        <a:lumMod val="50000"/>
    </a:schemeClr>
</a:solidFill>
```

Unfortunately, there isn't a way in VBA to apply lumMod or lumOff directly. Instead, you need to apply **.PictureEffects** parameters, then find out which PictureEffect code creates the necessary visual effect. **msoEffectBrightnessContrast** and **msoEffectSaturation** will be able to set the same color values with some experimentation. Here is Microsoft's enumeration of Picture Effects: [MsoPictureEffectType enumeration (Office)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/office.msopictureeffecttype)

Comment: John - thanks for your time and insight, really appreciate it.